# Tried to learn eBPF tail call, fails to attach kprobe

Tags: linux, ebpf, bcc-bpf

Hi I'm trying to learn how to use eBPF maps so I tried to run the simple code I found on BCC document.

```
import os
import socket
import time
import logging
import signal
import sys
import zmq
import json
import yaml
import netifaces as ni
from bcc import BPF
from ctypes import *

b = BPF(src_file="tailcall_test.c")
tail_fn = b.load_func("tail_call", BPF.KPROBE)
prog_array = b.get_table("prog_array")
prog_array[c_int(2)] = c_int(tail_fn.fd)
b.attach_kprobe(event="some_kprobe_event", fn_name = "do_tail_call")
```

and here's the c code that I used which name is :tailcall_test.c :

```
#include <uapi/linux/ptrace.h>
#include <net/sock.h>
#include <bcc/proto.h>
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <uapi/linux/bpf.h>

BPF_PROG_ARRAY(prog_array, 10);

int tail_call(void *ctx) {
        bpf_trace_printk("tail-call\n");
        return 0;
}

int do_tail_call(void *ctx) {
        bpf_trace_printk("Original program\n");
        prog_array.call(ctx, 2);
        return 0;
}
```

I wasn't so sure which headers or libraries need to be included so I dumped everything in there.. sorry about the dirty code :(

Anyways, it gives me this error when I try to run it :

```
cannot attach kprobe, probe entry may not exist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tailcall_test.py", line 18, in <module>
    b.attach_kprobe(event="some_kprobe_event", fn_name = "do_tail_call")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bcc/__init__.py", line 648, in attach_kprobe
    (fn_name, event))
Exception: Failed to attach BPF program do_tail_call to kprobe some_kprobe_event
```

Any help..?
Thank you so much in advance.

Plus, if you guys have any recommendation to check on to learn how to use eBPF tail calls, I would really appreciate it if you guys would share them with me.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I'd almost conclude that kernel doesn't have bpf compiled in, but that is probably premature. What I would do from here is to see if and which modules are compiled into the kernel and which are modules: `grep -i 'bpf' /boot/config-$(uname -r)` (Please substitute your own kernel version

Comment: The results of the command are : 
CONFIG_CGROUP_BPF=y
CONFIG_BPF=y
CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL=y
CONFIG_BPF_JIT_ALWAYS_ON=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_BPF=m
CONFIG_NET_CLS_BPF=m
CONFIG_NET_ACT_BPF=m
CONFIG_BPF_JIT=y
CONFIG_BPF_STREAM_PARSER=y
CONFIG_LWTUNNEL_BPF=y
CONFIG_HAVE_EBPF_JIT=y
CONFIG_BPF_EVENTS=y
CONFIG_TEST_BPF=m

and my kernel version is :
4.15.0-52-generic

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/issues/2071 ?

Comment: Oh, btw., you have to be root to get such kprobe access.

Comment: Oh I did check the url you added on the comment but I didn't do root when I was running that code! and it solved the problem! Thank you so much for helping me out! I really appreciate it :D

Comment: Glad it works. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I didn't have time to finish typing my answer before the cause of the issue was found by Roadowl in the comments :). Since there was a second part in the question about references for tail calls, and I have written that bit anyway, I post it just in case it can be helpful.

- Just for future reference, bcc documentation has [a paragraph on tail calls](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/docs/reference_guide.md#27-mapcall), but by the look of your code you found it already :).
- If you want to understand how tail calls work, I would suggest having a look at Cilium's documentation, in particular [the section on tail calls](http://docs.cilium.io/en/latest/bpf/#tail-calls). Keep in mind that bcc provides some wrappers (such as the `.call()` function) that won't be covered in Cilium's doc, but it should help you understand what is happening under the hood anyway.
- bcc itself does not seem to use tail calls a lot, I could only find [one networking example](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/examples/networking/tunnel_monitor/monitor.c) that seems to use it (although I did not search thoroughly).
- You can find some simple example programs using tail calls in the iproute2 repository (a [simple one](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/tree/examples/bpf/legacy/bpf_tailcall.c), [one that loops](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/tree/examples/bpf/legacy/bpf_cyclic.c)). You can also find some in kernel [samples](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/samples/bpf) or [selftests](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/tools/testing/selftests/bpf): grep for `tail_call`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying to look for other codes I could reference to practice tailcalls and wasn't really being succesful on that but now I know where to look :D Thanks again!